# Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super

Say I have a multiple inheritance scenario:

```
class A(object):
    # code for A here

class B(object):
    # code for B here

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        # What's the right code to write here to ensure 
        # A.__init__ and B.__init__ get called?
```

There's two typical approaches to writing `C`'s `__init__`:

1. (old-style) `ParentClass.__init__(self)`
2. (newer-style) `super(DerivedClass, self).__init__()`

However, in either case, if the parent classes (`A` and `B`) [don't follow the same convention, then the code will not work correctly](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) (some may be missed, or get called multiple times).

So what's the correct way again?  It's easy to say "just be consistent, follow one or the other", but if `A` or `B` are from a 3rd party library, what then?  Is there an approach that can ensure that all parent class constructors get called (and in the correct order, and only once)?

Edit: to see what I mean, if I do:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering A")
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print("Leaving A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering B")
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("Leaving B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering C")
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        print("Leaving C")
```

Then I get:

```
Entering C
Entering A
Entering B
Leaving B
Leaving A
Entering B
Leaving B
Leaving C
```

Note that `B`'s init gets called twice.  If I do:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering A")
        print("Leaving A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering B")
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("Leaving B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering C")
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print("Leaving C")
```

Then I get:

```
Entering C
Entering A
Leaving A
Leaving C
```

Note that `B`'s init never gets called.  So it seems that unless I know/control the init's of the classes I inherit from (`A` and `B`) I cannot make a safe choice for the class I'm writing (`C`).

Comment: Related: [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/3357935)

Comment: Is this "[MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)" thing still relevant in Python 3?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Both ways work fine.  The approach using `super()` leads to greater flexibility for subclasses.

In the direct call approach, `C.__init__` can call both `A.__init__` and `B.__init__`.

When using `super()`, the classes need to be designed for cooperative multiple inheritance where `C` calls `super`, which invokes `A`'s code which will also call `super` which invokes `B`'s code.  See http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super for more detail on what can be done with `super`.

[Response question as later edited]

> So it seems that unless I know/control the init's of the classes I
>   inherit from (A and B) I cannot make a safe choice for the class I'm
>   writing (C).

The referenced article shows how to handle this situation by adding a wrapper class around `A` and `B`.  There is a worked-out example in the section titled "How to Incorporate a Non-cooperative Class".

One might wish that multiple inheritance were easier, letting you effortlessly compose Car and Airplane classes to get a FlyingCar, but the reality is that separately designed components often need adapters or wrappers before fitting together as seamlessly as we would like :-)

One other thought:  if you're unhappy with composing functionality using multiple inheritance, you can use composition for complete control over which methods get called on which occasions.

Comment: No, they don't.  If B's init doesn't call super, then B's init will not be called if we do the `super().__init__()` approach.  If I call `A.__init__()` and `B.__init__()` directly, then (if A and B do call `super`) I get B's init being called multiple times.

Comment: @AdamParkin To use super() with multiple inheritance, the classes need  to be __designed__ for cooperative multiple inheritance using the principles outlined in the the article.   Your other choice is to let *C* call both *A* and *B*'s code directly.

Comment: @AdamParkin (regarding your question as edited):  If one of the parent classes isn't designed for use with *super()*, it can usually be wrapped in a way that adds the *super* call.  The referenced article shows a worked-out example in the section titled "How to Incorporate a Non-cooperative Class".

Comment: Somehow I managed to miss that section when I read the article.  *Exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, the adapter approach means you now need to replicate the interface of the class you're inheriting from in the adapter.  Ick, but safe.

Comment: If you are writing python (hopefully 3!) and using inheritance of any sort, but especially multiple, then http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super should be required reading.

Comment: So what if you want to pass take two parameters into C, and pass one parameter to A, and pass the other to B?

Comment: Upvoting because we finally know why we don't have flying cars when we were sure we would have by now.

Answer (score 262):

The answer to your question depends on one very important aspect: **Are your base classes designed for multiple inheritance?**

There are 3 different scenarios:

1. ### The base classes are unrelated, standalone classes.

   If your base classes are separate entities that are capable of functioning independently and they don't know each other, they're *not* designed for multiple inheritance. Example:

   ```
   class Foo:
       def __init__(self):
           self.foo = 'foo'

   class Bar:
       def __init__(self, bar):
           self.bar = bar
   ```

   **Important:** Notice that neither `Foo` nor `Bar` calls `super().__init__()`! This is why your code didn't work correctly. Because of the way diamond inheritance works in python, **classes whose base class is `object` should not call `super().__init__()`**. As you've noticed, doing so would break multiple inheritance because you end up calling another class's `__init__` rather than `object.__init__()`. *(**Disclaimer:** Avoiding `super().__init__()` in `object`-subclasses is my personal recommendation and by no means an agreed-upon consensus in the python community. Some people prefer to use `super` in every class, arguing that you can always write an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) if the class doesn't behave as you expect.)*

   This also means that you should never write a class that inherits from `object` and doesn't have an `__init__` method. Not defining a `__init__` method at all has the same effect as calling `super().__init__()`. If your class inherits directly from `object`, make sure to add an empty constructor like so:

   ```
   class Base(object):
       def __init__(self):
           pass
   ```

   Anyway, in this situation, you will have to call each parent constructor manually. There are two ways to do this:

   - **Without `super`**

     ```
     class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
         def __init__(self, bar='bar'):
             Foo.__init__(self)  # explicit calls without super
             Bar.__init__(self, bar)
     ```
   - **With `super`**

     ```
     class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
         def __init__(self, bar='bar'):
             super().__init__()  # this calls all constructors up to Foo
             super(Foo, self).__init__(bar)  # this calls all constructors after Foo up
                                             # to Bar
     ```

   Each of these two methods has its own advantages and disadvantages. If you use `super`, your class will support [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33469090/1222951). On the other hand, it's easier to make mistakes. For example if you change the order of `Foo` and `Bar` (like `class FooBar(Bar, Foo)`), you'd have to update the `super` calls to match. Without `super` you don't have to worry about this, and the code is much more readable.
2. ### One of the classes is a mixin.

   A [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) is a class that's *designed* to be used with multiple inheritance. This means we don't have to call both parent constructors manually, because the mixin will automatically call the 2nd constructor for us. Since we only have to call a single constructor this time, we can do so with `super` to avoid having to hard-code the parent class's name.

   Example:

   ```
   class FooMixin:
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # forwards all unused arguments
           self.foo = 'foo'

   class Bar:
       def __init__(self, bar):
           self.bar = bar

   class FooBar(FooMixin, Bar):
       def __init__(self, bar='bar'):
           super().__init__(bar)  # a single call is enough to invoke
                                  # all parent constructors

           # NOTE: `FooMixin.__init__(self, bar)` would also work, but isn't
           # recommended because we don't want to hard-code the parent class.
   ```

   The important details here are:

   - The mixin calls `super().__init__()` and passes through any arguments it receives.
   - The subclass inherits from the mixin *first*: `class FooBar(FooMixin, Bar)`. If the order of the base classes is wrong, the mixin's constructor will never be called.
3. ### All base classes are designed for cooperative inheritance.

   Classes designed for cooperative inheritance are a lot like mixins: They pass through all unused arguments to the next class. Like before, we just have to call `super().__init__()` and all parent constructors will be chain-called.

   Example:

   ```
   class CoopFoo:
       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(**kwargs)  # forwards all unused arguments
           self.foo = 'foo'

   class CoopBar:
       def __init__(self, bar, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(**kwargs)  # forwards all unused arguments
           self.bar = bar

   class CoopFooBar(CoopFoo, CoopBar):
       def __init__(self, bar='bar'):
           super().__init__(bar=bar)  # pass all arguments on as keyword
                                      # arguments to avoid problems with
                                      # positional arguments and the order
                                      # of the parent classes
   ```

   In this case, the order of the parent classes doesn't matter. We might as well inherit from `CoopBar` first, and the code would still work the same. But that's only true because all arguments are passed as keyword arguments. Using positional arguments would make it easy to get the order of the arguments wrong, so it's customary for cooperative classes to accept only keyword arguments.

   This is also an exception to the rule I mentioned earlier: Both `CoopFoo` and `CoopBar` inherit from `object`, but they still call `super().__init__()`. If they didn't, there would be no cooperative inheritance.

Bottom line: The correct implementation depends on the classes you're inheriting from.

The constructor is part of a class's public interface. If the class is designed as a mixin or for cooperative inheritance, that must be documented. If the docs don't mention anything of the sort, it's safe to assume that the class *isn't* designed for cooperative multiple inheritance.

Comment: Your second point blew me away. I only ever saw Mixins to the right of the actual super class and thought they were pretty loose and dangerous, since you can't check if the class you are mixing into has the attributes you are expecting it to have. I never thought about putting a general `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` into the mixin and writing it first. It makes so much sense.

Comment: If one class is Mixin, and Mixin and parent class has a method with the same name but different implementation, which one the child class will use?

Comment: @Mohammad Depends on the order in which you inherit from those 2 classes. `class Child(Mixin, Parent):` will use the method from `Mixin`, `class Child(Parent, Mixin):` will use the method from `Parent`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Thanks. If Child class has a method with the same name in Mixin class, does it overwrite method in Mixin class?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, of course.

Comment: This is most likely the best explanation I have ever seen on multiple class inheritance and how super() works.

Answer (score 27):

Either approach ("new style" or "old style") will work **if you have control over the source code for `A` and `B`**. Otherwise, use of an adapter class might be necessary.

#### Source code accessible: Correct use of "new style"

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> A")
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print("<- A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> B")
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("<- B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> C")
        # Use super here, instead of explicit calls to __init__
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print("<- C")
```

```
>>> C()
-> C
-> A
-> B
<- B
<- A
<- C
```

Here, [method resolution order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) (MRO) dictates the following:

- `C(A, B)` dictates `A` first, then `B`. MRO is `C -> A -> B -> object`.
- `super(A, self).__init__()` continues along the MRO chain initiated in `C.__init__` to `B.__init__`.
- `super(B, self).__init__()` continues along the MRO chain initiated in `C.__init__` to `object.__init__`.

You could say that this case is *designed for multiple inheritance*.

#### Source code accessible: Correct use of "old style"

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> A")
        print("<- A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> B")
        # Don't use super here.
        print("<- B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> C")
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        print("<- C")
```

```
>>> C()
-> C
-> A
<- A
-> B
<- B
<- C
```

Here, MRO does not matter, since `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` are called explicitly. `class C(B, A):` would work just as well.

Although this case is not "designed" for multiple inheritance in the new style as the previous one was, multiple inheritance is still possible.

---

Now, what if `A` and `B` are from a third party library - i.e., **you have no control over the source code for `A` and `B`**? The short answer: You must design an adapter class that implements the necessary `super` calls, then use an empty class to define the MRO (see [Raymond Hettinger's article on `super`](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) - especially the section, "How to Incorporate a Non-cooperative Class").

#### Third-party parents: `A` does not implement `super`; `B` does

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> A")
        print("<- A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> B")
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("<- B")

class Adapter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> C")
        A.__init__(self)
        super(Adapter, self).__init__()
        print("<- C")

class C(Adapter, B):
    pass
```

```
>>> C()
-> C
-> A
<- A
-> B
<- B
<- C
```

Class `Adapter` implements `super` so that `C` can define the MRO, which comes into play when `super(Adapter, self).__init__()` is executed.

And what if it's the other way around?

#### Third-party parents: `A` implements `super`; `B` does not

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> A")
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print("<- A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> B")
        print("<- B")

class Adapter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("-> C")
        super(Adapter, self).__init__()
        B.__init__(self)
        print("<- C")

class C(Adapter, A):
    pass
```

```
>>> C()
-> C
-> A
<- A
-> B
<- B
<- C
```

Same pattern here, except the order of execution is switched in `Adapter.__init__`; `super` call first, then explicit call. Notice that each case with third-party parents requires a unique adapter class.

> So it seems that unless I know/control the init's of the classes I inherit from (`A` and `B`) I cannot make a safe choice for the class I'm writing (`C`).

Although you can handle the cases where you don't *control* the source code of `A` and `B` by using an adapter class, it is true that you must *know* how the init's of the parent classes implement `super` (if at all) in order to do so.

Comment: In Source code accessible: Correct use of "new style", How is -> B & <- B getting printed. If I comment "super(A, self).__init__()" , then it wont print "->B" & "<- B". & if I comment "super(B, self).__init__()" , then everything remains same. Whats actually happening???

Comment: @ShambhavAgrawal As stated in the section you mentioned, the MRO for this example is `C -> A -> B -> object`. Whenever a call to `super()` is made, execution is passed up the MRO chain. So `super(A, self).__init__()` passes off to `B.__init__()` (which prints "-> B" & "<- B") and `super(B, self).__init__()` passes off to `object.__init__()` (which doesn't print anything).

Answer (score 11):

As Raymond said in his answer, a direct call to `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` works fine, and your code would be readable.

However, it does not use the inheritance link between `C` and those classes. Exploiting that link gives you more consistancy and make eventual refactorings easier and less error-prone. An example of how to do that:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("entering c")
        for base_class in C.__bases__:  # (A, B)
             base_class.__init__(self)
        print("leaving c")
```

Comment: The best answer imho. Found this particularly helpful as it is more futureproof

Comment: Simple and straight to the point. Works with Python 3 in 2020 as well -- it's indeed future-proof :-)

Answer (score 3):

This article helps to explain cooperative multiple inheritance:

*[The wonders of cooperative inheritance, or using super in Python 3](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127)*

It mentions the useful method `mro()` that shows you the method resolution order. In your second example, where you call `super` in `A`, the `super` call continues on in [MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). The next class in the order is `B`, this is why `B`'s init is called the first time.

Here's a more technical article from the official Python site:

*[The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)*

Answer (score 2):

If you are multiply sub-classing classes from third party libraries, then no, there is no blind approach to calling the base class `__init__` methods (or any other methods) that actually works regardless of how the base classes are programmed.

`super` makes it *possible* to write classes designed to cooperatively implement methods as part of complex multiple inheritance trees which need not be known to the class author. But there's no way to use it to correctly inherit from arbitrary classes that may or may not use `super`.

Essentially, whether a class is designed to be sub-classed using `super` or with direct calls to the base class is a property which is part of the class' "public interface", and it should be documented as such. If you're using third-party libraries in the way that the library author expected and the library has reasonable documentation, it would normally tell you what you are required to do to subclass particular things. If not, then you'll have to look at the source code for the classes you're sub-classing and see what their base-class-invocation convention is. If you're combining multiple classes from one or more third-party libraries in a way that the library authors *didn't* expect, then it may not be possible to consistently invoke super-class methods *at all*; if class A is part of a hierarchy using `super` and class B is part of a hierarchy that doesn't use super, then neither option is guaranteed to work. You'll have to figure out a strategy that happens to work for each particular case.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Well, you already wrote and linked to an article with some thoughts about that in your answer, so I don't think I have much to add to that. :) I don't think it's possible to generically adapt any non-super-using class to a super-hierarchy though; you have to come up with a solution tailored to the particular classes involved.

Answer (score 1):

I added a small utility library, [supers](https://github.com/LukasHedegaard/supers), which makes this kind of scenario simpler to handle. It works as follows:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering A")
        print("Leaving A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering B")
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("Leaving B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Entering C")
        supers(self).__init__()
        print("Leaving C")
```

Output when creating C:

```
Entering C
Entering A
Leaving A
Entering B
Leaving B
Leaving C
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, suppose you got the [MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) chain
2. From the lowest level subclass **init** method on, any class which using super() method would jump into corresponding chain position, as any class which not using super() method would jump out corresponding chain position.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have implemented the multiple inheritance in Python 3 using super()

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a, b, **kwargs):
      print("Class A initiallised")
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      print("Class A initiallisation done")

  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.a} and {self.b}"

  def display_a(self):
      return f"{self.a} and {self.b}"

class C:
   def __init__(self, c, d, **kwargs):
      print("Class C initiallised")
      self.c = c
      self.d = d
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      print("class c initiallisation done")

   def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.c} and {self.d}"

   def display_c(self):
       return f"{self.c} and {self.d}"


class D(A,C):
   def __init__(self, e, **kwargs):
       print("Class D initiallised")
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.e = e
       print("Class D initiallisation done")

   def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.e} is e,{self.b} is b,{self.a} is a,{self.d} is d,{self.c} is c"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   d = D(a=12, b=13, c=14, d=15, e=16)
   print(d)
   d.display_c()
   d.display_a()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have implemented the super method in Python inheritance and achieved the required solution:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("from A")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("from B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
          A.__init__(self)
          B.__init__(self)
          print("from C")

c = C()
```

Answer (score 0):

It follows the [MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) rule and *A init* is called.

Comment: Author already knows this.The question is how to call every child's class `__init__`.