# Adapting non-cooperative superclass with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose I am using a library that provides the following classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B")
        super().__init__()
```

I then define a mixin and a child class:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print("C")
        super().__init__()

class D(B, C): 
    def __init__(self):
        print("D")
        super().__init__()
```

The output of creating a new `D` is

```
D
B
A
```

My goal is for C's `__init__` to also be called when D is initialized, *without being able to modify B or A*. Desired output would be

```
D
B
A
C
```

There are a variety of questions on using `super` with multiple inheritance, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/2514228) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16305177/2514228). From [this post](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), I understand that for the cooperative subclassing pattern to work, and `C.__init__` to be called, `B` and `A` need to also call `super`, which would return `C` in the method resolution order. Hettinger recommends writing an adapter class to deal with this "non-cooperative" situation. I can write an adapter class for B, but unlike in Hettinger's example, B is the primary class I inherit from, rather than a mixin. My understanding is that I would have to "rewrite" every method that B implements in its adapter for this to work, which seems infeasible, especially if B is a large library class that might change behavior in the future.

So is there any way to get C's initialization behavior without being able to adapt B or A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #1 golden rule of mixins:

*Always inherit from the mixin **first***.

---

Proper mixins are designed to support multiple inheritance, i.e. they have a constructor with `*args, **kwargs` that calls `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` (or they don't have a constructor at all). A constructor like this is completely transparent and unnoticeable; it doesn't get in the way of the child class's constructor.

When the child class (`D`) calls `super().__init__()` it'll call the mixin's (`C`'s) constructor, which will in turn call `B`'s constructor. In other words, your problem is solved simply by reordering `D`'s parent classes.

```
class D(C, B): 
    def __init__(self):
        print("D")
        super().__init__()

D()  # output: D C B A
```

---

If, for some reason, you absolutely have to call the constructors in the order `D B A C`, you should call the parent classes' constructors *explicitly*, without `super()`:

```
class D(B, C): 
    def __init__(self):
        print("D")
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self)

D()  # output: D B A C
```