# Python 2.7: Self works as positional but not as keyword argument

Tags: python-2.7, self, keyword-argument

Here is a minimal example:

This works in both python 3.5 and 2.7:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, foo):
    self._foo = foo

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, foo):
    A.__init__(self, foo=foo)

b = B(1)
```

Change line:

```
    A.__init__(self, foo=foo)
```

to

```
    A.__init__(self=self, foo=foo)
```

In python 3.5 works without problems, but in python 2.7 you will receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "self_key.py", line 9, in <module>
    b = B(1)
  File "self_key.py", line 7, in __init__
    A.__init__(self=self, foo=foo)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Is self as keyword argument forbidden in python 2.7 or is this a bug?

### Update

I'm aware that python will use the first parameter of a bound function to pass the reference to the object from which has been called. I also know that the `__init__` function expects that this parameter is an instance of the class. In this case `A.__init__` is unbound so we must provide that parameter manually.

When I asked about *self as keyword argument forbidden* I'm speaking about self as "the first parameter of `__init__`", which is supposed to receive a reference of the object to initialize. The name of the variable itself doesn't matter. We can perfectly change the name to *this*:, for example:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(this, foo):
    this._foo = foo

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, foo):
    A.__init__(this=self, foo=foo)

b = B(1)
```

And it will be the same.

My question is why when calling the function we can perfectly specify that parameter as a positional argument (`A.__init__(self, foo=foo)`) but when we try to pass it as a keyword argument (`A.__init__(this=self, foo=foo)`) python 2.7 throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.

Source: [Python Documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments)

Comment: By reading this I've got the impression this applies for function definitions, rather than calling.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **don't have to** use `self` keyword unless you're consistent. Check out this example, where I changed `self` to `test` :

```
class funcs():
    def init(test, a, b):
        test.a=a
        test.b=b

    def plus(test):
        c = test.a + test.b
        print"%d + %d = %d" %(test.a, test.b, c)

    def minus(test):
        c = test.a - test.b
        print"%d - %d = %d" %(test.a, test.b, c)

obj = funcs()
obj.init(10, 6)
obj.plus()
obj.minus()
```

You can try to mix those instance name, so it won't be named `self`.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(a_obj, foo):
    a_obj._foo = foo

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, test, foo):
    A.__init__(self, a_obj=test, foo=foo) # here you pass object of class B and actually another object of class B

a = A(2)
b = B(a, 1)
```

Giving output:

```
A.__init__(self, a_obj=test, foo=foo) 
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a_obj'
```

I'm not sure what actually you want to accomplish by passing those object like this. In your code, `self` in class A and `self` in class B are not the same objects.

I suppose that here: `A.__init__(self=self, foo=foo)` you are doing something like `A_instance=B_instance` (`self=self`)

Comment: I'm just calling the parent's `__init__`. I'm using this approach instead of using `super()` in order to control the `__init__` call order of the parents in multiple inheritance, just like this [http://stackoverflow.com/q/9575409/5705400]. So self in A and self in B should be the same object since im passing a reference of B to the `__init__` method of A. Which is okay since B inherits from A, so it's also an A.