# Why super(A, self).__init__() doesn't call A's __init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__()')

class D(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print('D.__init__()')

D()
```

The output is:

```
D.__init__()
```

This is unexpected to me. According to my understanding, `super(A, self).__init__()` should have called `A`'s ctor, thus should have printed "A.**init**()".

I have read a few other questions about `super()` but I don't think they answer my question exactly.

My python is 3.5.3.

Comment: Change it to `super(D, self)` or `super()`

Comment: I always found `A.__init__(self)` syntax more intuitive than `super`.

Comment: what vaultah means is that you're calling the constructor of the _parent_ of `A`.

Comment: But if I have multi-inheritance, how do I call the __init__() of a particular parent class? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way

Comment: Since you're using Python 3, you can use the no-argument version of `super()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your not getting what you expect is because you are calling the `__init__()` function of *`A`'s* parent class - which is `object` - so `A`'s `__init__()` is never called. You need to do `super(D, self).__init__()` instead to call the constructor of `D`'s parent class, `A`:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__()')


>>> class D(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__() # Change A to D
        print('D.__init__()')


>>> D()
A.__init__()
D.__init__()
<__main__.D object at 0x7fecc5bbcf60>
>>>
```

Also, note that in Python 3 you no longer have to explicitly inherit from `object`. All classes inherit from `object` by default. See [*Section 3.3 New-style and old-style classes*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) in Python 2's docs for a more detailed overview.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. And for the extra tip on `object`.

Comment: And for the benefit of other readers. I also found Jean-F. F.'s comment to the OP useful, i.e. check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way, which in term refer to https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/.