# How do I shuffle a deck that a dealer inherits?

Tags: python

I built a deck of cards that can be shuffled. I built the player module and had the dealer class inherit the deck. (as the dealer is the one to shuffle the cards, rather than the deck of cards shuffling itself) I tried to import both into a main and have the dealer shuffle. Nope, things start breaking.

After a while, I started just doing trial and error, adding random ()'s and `self`'s and whatever you can think of. Nothing worked. The main file is pretty much erased at this point, because I'm not just understanding anything from youtube or anything, really.

```
import random as rd


class Card:
    card_rank = [str(n) for n in range(2, 10)]
    card_rank.extend(['Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'])
    card_suit = ['Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts']

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        assert 2 <= rank <= 14 and 1 <= suit <= 4
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} of {}'.format(Card.card_rank[self.rank - 2], Card.card_suit[self.suit - 1])


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(rank, suit) for rank in range(2, 14 + 1) for suit in range(1, 4 + 1)]

    def is_empty(self):
        return not self.cards

    def pick(self):
        rd.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self.cards.pop()
```

> ```
> import CardDeck
>
>
> class Player:
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.hand = []
>
>
> class Human(Player):
>     def __init__(self):
>         super(Human, self).__init__()
>         self.name = input()
>
>
> class Dealer(Player, CardDeck.Deck):
>     def __init__(self):
>         super(Dealer, self).__init__()
>
>     def deck_shuffle(self):
>         while not CardDeck.Deck.is_empty:
>             print(CardDeck.Deck.pick)
> ```

```
>     import CardDeck as cd
>     import Players as pl
>     
>     
>     dealer = pl.Dealer
>     
>     
>     dealer.deck_shuffle
```

I want the dealer to shuffle the cards. I'm looking to see if it works by printing out the deck. I plan on doing more, but for now, I'm very stuck. (sorry for the formatting, this site confuses me on that)

Comment: Why do you inherit? The dealer and the deck are two completely different classes / objects. Instead add a method shuffle to the dealer that takes a deck as argument and returns the shuffled deck.

Comment: Research Inheritence VS composition

Comment: A Dealer is no a deck, he _has_ a Deck .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `(` and `)` in function calls, and some minor things in your `Players.py` file.

To make a function call, you need to put the function arguments after its name.

i.e. `is_empty()` and not `is_empty`

Also here

```py
dealer = pl.Dealer ()

dealer.deck_shuffle ()
```

```py
import CardDeck


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []


class Human(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Human, self).__init__()
        self.name = input()


class Dealer(CardDeck.Deck, Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dealer, self).__init__()

    def deck_shuffle(self):
        while not self.is_empty():
            print(self.pick())
```

Changes to note:

- You didn't initialize the `Dealer` because you didn't put `()`
- You didn't make the shuffle (same reason)
- Your Player's `deck_shuffle` method should have called the functions on it's instance

Without the parenthesis, you are referencing the function/method, instead of calling it.
e.g.

```
>>> dealer.deck_shuffle
<bound method Dealer.deck_shuffle of <Players.Dealer object at 0x7fcbdc2ff4e0>>
```

Same with the way you tried to call `is_empty` method.

```
>>> CardDeck.Deck.is_empty
<function Deck.is_empty at 0x7fcbdc297730>
```

If you try to call a method which isn't [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python), you'll get an exception:

```
>>> CardDeck.Deck.is_empty()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: is_empty() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

You need to have an instance of that object upon which the method will function.

Answer (score 2):

The deck is a list so you can import `random` and use `random.shuffle(deck)` on the deck instance u create either global or in dealer's hand.

this is a [black jack script](https://github.com/Pierian-Data/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp/blob/master/08-Milestone%20Project%20-%202/04-Milestone%20Project%202%20-%20Solution%20Code.ipynb) from a course i was following it will help you alot. also it got some explanition to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the inheritance, you need to make sure you initialise all super classes.

In your `Dealer` class you call `super(Dealer, self).__init__()` which only initialises the `Player` superclass. Therefore the `cards` field from `Deck` is never created.

You either need to add an explicit `Deck.__init__(self)` call in the dealer's `__init__` or add `super().__init__()` to `Player`.

For more information look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way).

Then, in your `deck_shuffle` you just call `self.pick()`.

Edit:
In summary, the code should be:
CardDeck.py unchanged
Players.py:

```
import CardDeck


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        # Added superclass initialisation (for cooperative multiple inheritance)
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.hand = []

# Unchanged
class Human(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Human, self).__init__()
        self.name = input()


class Dealer(Player, CardDeck.Deck):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dealer, self).__init__()

    def deck_shuffle(self):
        while not self.is_empty:
            print(self.pick())
```

and you call it like:

```
import Players as pl

dealer = pl.Dealer()
dealer.deck_shuffle()
```

Comment: Despite all the help, I'm still not getting it. I've tried this and that from the answers here but I'm just too stupid to get this.