# Using a Mixin to Store Configs in a Class (with inheritance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, mixins

I have lots of defaults being loaded from a config file and stored in a struct-style class (no methods, just variables).

I then have two classes, one defining a `Molecule`, another defining a specific kind of molecule, here called `Ligand` which inherits from `Molecule`. I want `Ligand` to have access to all methods and variables from `Molecule` and all variables from `DefaultsMixin`. I'm trying to use a mixin for this but I think I'm misusing `super()`. A rough outline of the classes are as follows:

```py
class DefaultsMixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memory = 4
        self.threads = 2

class Molecule:
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.name = name

class Ligand(DefaultsMixin, Molecule):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.atoms = ['C', 'H']
```

Inheritance is right to left, hence the order in `Ligand()`.

I want to avoid using composition as I want to simply call the defaults by name e.g.

```py
# What I want to achieve using mixin
mol = Ligand('methane')
mol.threads
>>> 2

# What I want to avoid using composition
# (self.defaults = Defaults() inside Ligand class instead of using mixin)
mol = Ligand('methane')
mol.defaults.threads
>>> 2
```

How can I correctly use `super()` to get this mixin to work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the mixin example [gCoh's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way), you'll see that you need to add *args and **kwargs to the mixin to pass thru unused parameters. Also (seems counter-intuitive to me at least) you need to call super from the mixin not your Molecule class.

Is this the behavior you desire?

```py
class DefaultsMixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.memory = 4
        self.threads = 2


class Molecule:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Ligand(DefaultsMixin, Molecule):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.atoms = ['C', 'H']


mol = Ligand('methane')
print(f'The number of threads is {mol.threads}')
print(f'The atoms are {mol.atoms}')
print(f'The name is {mol.name}')
```

outputs:

```
The number of threads is 2
The atoms are ['C', 'H']
The name is methane
```

Comment: This works (thank you!) but I'm a little confused as to why `DefaultsMixin` needs to take `*args` and `**kwargs` if I'm not passing any variables.

Comment: But you are passing a parameter - the name parameter. The mixin init is called first and the name parameter is passed through via the *args and **kwargs in the mixin `super()` that executes the Molecule init.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. The mixin takes the argument and passes it across, even if it doesn't use it itself. Great, thank you!

Comment: Yes - Legand `super()` calls the Mixin `init()` and the Mixin `super()` calls the Molecule `init()` with the unused args.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the parent object's **init** method

Please see [Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way)