# Pythonic way of passing different arguments in multiple inheritance setup

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, superclass

Consider the following snippet:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b1, b2):
        self._b1 = b1
        self._b2 = b2

class C(B, A):
    def __init__(self, b1, b2, a):
        super().__init__(b1=b1, b2=b2, a=a)
```

Then I will encounter the following error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'

To resolve it, I initilize the superclass 'A', as follows:

```
class C(B, A):
    def __init__(self, b1, b2, a):
        super().__init__(b1=b1, b2=b2)
        A.__init__(self, a=a)
```

Yet another solution:

```
class C(B, A):
    def __init__(self, b1, b2, a):
        super().__init__(b1=b1, b2=b2)
        super(B, self).__init__(a=a)
```

I found these solutions in a try and error way. So, I'm wondering what is the most elegant way of passing arguments to multiple superclasses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling parent class \_\_init\_\_ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way)

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm looking for the logic behind either of the solutions. That post does not explain why arguments are not being attributed to the relevant parent classes.

Comment: because `super()` can only reference a single class, and that class is calculated using the mro (or method resolution order). Do a research on that.

Comment: @DeepSpace In fact the philosophy behind `__mro__` is to be able to reference multiple delegates in the correct order. So, I do not think `super()` is meant to reference a single class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have classes that will be composed with other classes that they don't need to know about (specifically, don't need or don't care about their arguments), you can use the `**` Python Parameter/argument passing syntax to fold and unfold arguments into a dictionary.

In other words, your code would be like:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        self._a = a
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B:
    def __init__(self, b1, b2, **kwargs):
        self._b1 = b1
        self._b2 = b2
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class C(B, A):
    def __init__(self, b1, b2, a):
        super().__init__(b1=b1, b2=b2, a=a)
```

Also note that in your base-classes `__init__`  code above you were not calling `super()`, so just the `__init__` of the closer super-class would ever be executed.

`super()` in Python do all the magic needed for multiple-inheritance to work correctly. One of the most complete articles on that is still [Python's super considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

In short terms what takes place: whenever you create a class, using or not multiple parents, Python creates a `__mro__` attribute to it - this is the "method resolution order" for that class, indicating the order that methods and attributes will be searched for in the ancestors.

The algorithm for calculating the MRO itself is complex, a bit thought to explain, but which can be reasonably trusted as it "just does the right thing". Up to today the only place I found it described in full is on [its original presentation in Python 2.3 documentation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), more than 15 years ago. (optional reading,as it "does the right thing".)

What `super()` does is to create a proxy object that will pick the next class in the "mro" sequence for the original calling class, and search methods directly in its `__dict__` - if not found, it will go the next entry on the "mro". 
So, if you only consider the class `B`, `super().__init__()` inside its body would call `object.__init__`. If "kwargs" is empty at this point, as it will be if `B()` is called with only the parameters it cares about, that is just what is wanted.

When `B.__init__` is run in a chainned `super()` call from a class "C" composed with "B" and "A", whoever, the `super()` in `B.__init__` will be using "C"'s MRO - and the next class is "A" - so `A.__init__` is called with all unconsumed keyword arguments.

Comment: With your answer I learnt the cooperative design above. But still cannot understand why in my initial example, simple positional arguments are not being striped-off by `super()` in `C`? Why do we need to call `super()` in `A` and `B`? In my example `C.__mro__` is `(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)`

Comment: Technically, in _this_ example you would not need to call super() from `A` - but you gain nothing from doing so, while keeping your project future proof if you do - as other inheritance hierarchies might be combined later into your subclasses, and maybe some class could end up with a superclass that would end up between "A" and "object" in its MRO.

Comment: And `super()` won't "strip" any arguments by itself. Each method in each class takes care of taking the arguments it needs. The named parameters explicitly make the language itself attribute the arguments with those names to that parameters, while keeping all others in the "kwargs" as a dictionary.