# How to use `super` in multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

Let suppose we have defined two classes:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0
```

Now, we want to define a third class `C` that inherits from `A` and `B`:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)   # how to do this using super()
        B.__init__(self)   # how to do this using super()
```

Comment: FWIW, I've indirectly answered this in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50465583/1222951). (The answer is `super().__init__()` followed by `super(A, self).__init__()`.)

Comment: Does this post answer your question ? [super multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Plus see rhettinger's [super considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super). which he links to from his own answer to that question.

Comment: Have you tried looking for an answer anywhere before asking? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134600/4744341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify whether you are Python 2 or Python 3 and it matters as we shall see. But either way, if you will be using `super()` in a derived class to initialize the base classes, then the base classes must use `super()` also. So,

**For Python 3:**

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = 0

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = 0

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

**For Python 2 (where classes must be new-style classes) or Python 3**

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.a = 0

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = 0

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
```

Comment: I use Python 3. But I don't understand why adding super() in base classes solve the problem?

Comment: @ThunderPheonix You should read the comment and link posted by Daniel Roseman to your original post, i.e. [Deep Thoughts by Raymond Hettinger](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), in particular the section **Python’s super() considered super!** and the sub-section **Practical Advice**.