# super().__init__() and the __dict__ method

Tags: python

The `__dict__` method does not produce the same result when the inherited classes are initialized directly instead of using the using `super().__init__()`. Why?:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att_a = "A"    

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att_b = "B"

class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        self.att_c = "C"

    def get_att(self):
        print(self.__dict__) 

c = C()

c.get_att()
```

Result: `{'attA': 'A', 'attB': 'B', 'attC': 'C'}`

Why using `super().__init__()` does not yield the same result:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att_a = "A"    

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att_b = "B"

class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # Modification
        self.att_c = "C"

    def get_att(self):
        print(self.__dict__) 

c = C()

c.get_att()
```

Result: `{'att_a': 'A', 'att_c': 'C'}`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409 .  Note that this problem is nothing to do with  `__dict__`. It's simply to do with what gets called and what doesn't: in your `super()` example, `A.__init__()` gets called and `B.__init__()` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super().__init__` only calls the *next* method in the MRO. `A.__init__` isn't calling `super().__init__`, so `B.__init__` never gets called.

*All* classes involved have to cooperate.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.att_a = "A"    


class B:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.att_b = "B"


class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.att_c = "C"

    def get_att(self):
        print(self.__dict__) 


# The MRO of C is [C, A, B, object]
# C.__init__ calls A.__init__
# A.__init__ calls B.__init__
# B.__init__ calls object.__init__
# object, as the root of the object hierarchy,
# does not use super().
c = C()

c.get_att()
```

The addition of `**kwargs` to all definitions is to accommodate any class that you may not even be aware of that extends `A`, `B`, or `C`. The class defining `__init__` cannot know ahead of time what class `super()` will invoke next.

Comment: I was about to mark the question as a duplicate but I have to say, none of the previous questions' answers are as clear as this one.

Comment: I usually feel a little guilty about answering questions like this, but in many cases I feel like an answer tailored to the specific question is more useful than a link to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__()` like any other method resolved by [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), ie. calls only one implementation.
Multiple inheritance only allows to find the 'right' method definitions in all subtrees: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super