# Is there a way for the child function that will inherit more than one parent function to access all of the parent's methods?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I am getting an error when making a third class that inherits the first two classes' attributes. The first class's function will be go through but when accessing the second class's function I am gettting an error:

```py
class3' object has no attribute 'othernum
```

Here is the code:

```py
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 10000
    def getNum(self):
        return self.number
    
class class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.othernum = 1111
    def displaynum(self):
        return self.othernum

class class3(class1, class2):
    pass

newperson = class3()
print(newperson.getNum())
print(newperson.displaynum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

```py
class class3(class1, class2):
    def __init__(self):
        class1.__init__(self)
        class2.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer presented by @Ishaan Sathaye is indeed correct. But be aware that there are several mechanisms for initializing base classes in a multiple inheritance hierarchy. See [Calling parent class **init** with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way), in particular the section with heading **All base classes are designed for cooperative inheritance.**

So, if your 3 classes were designed for cooperative inheritance, we would have:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = 10000
    def getNum(self):
        return self.number

class class2():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.othernum = 1111
    def displaynum(self):
        return self.othernum

class class3(class1, class2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

newperson = class3()
print(newperson.getNum())
print(newperson.displaynum())
```