# What is the purpose of `super().__init__()` in a base class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I understand that If `super().__init__()` is in a Python child class, it inherits the attributes of the parent class. I was just wondering what if we call `super().__init__()` in the parent class itself as shown below:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwrgs):
        super.__init__(args, kwrgs)
```

What is the use of calling a `super` in the parent class?

Comment: I would guess that this will call the constructor of the `object` class

Comment: It does not *inherits* parent's attribute, but rather calls its `__init__` method

Comment: Did you mean `super().__init__...`? Right now this code doesn't make much sense in many ways...

Comment: It *might* call `object.__init__`; it depends on the MRO of the value bound to `self`.

Answer (score 7):

For a simple example as in your question, indeed it makes no point. It will simply call `object.__init__` which doesn't do much and takes no arguments.

**BUT**, it makes a difference with [*multiple inheritance*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way). For example, the following code:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrgs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwrgs)
        print("in Base")

class SecondBase:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrgs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwrgs)
        print("in SecondBase")

class A(Base, SecondBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrgs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwrgs)
        print("in A")

class B(SecondBase, Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrgs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwrgs)
        print("in B")

print("A:")
A()
print("B:")
B()
```

Will produce:

```
A:
in SecondBase
in Base
in A
B:
in Base
in SecondBase
in B
```

As you can see, both `Base` and `SecondBase` are what you would call *base* classes, i.e. not inheriting. Still, because of `A` and `B`'s multiple inheritance, the `super()` calls return either `Base`/`SecondBase` respectively or `object`, depending on the `MRO`. This can be seen as:

```py
>>> A.mro()
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class '__main__.SecondBase'>, <class 'object'>]

>>> B.mro()
[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.SecondBase'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Comment: as understand the mro set the order of the classes parent initialization , in ur example it confusing cause it work in the exact opposite order , for A() the order is first Base but actually we see the prints coming from SecondBase

Comment: @AviC that just happens because the prints are after the `super` calls. So first we go down all the way in the MRO and then print as we go up. This is why the prints seem to be in reverse order. The order of `super` calls matches exactly the MRO