# Multiple inheritance in python using function super()

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Can I perform multiple inheritance(python 3) using the super keyword if my child class inherits more than 1 class?
Using `Parentobject.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs`) makes multiple inheritance easy
But how to perform the same using `super()`

```
    class A:
       def __init__(self,a):
          self.a=a
    class C:
       def __init__(self,b):
          self.b=b
    
    class D(C,A):
       def __init__(self,a,b):
          A.__init__(self,a)
          C.__init__(self,b)
```

Comment: You can't do this with arbitrary super classes. The super classes need to be designed for this kind of inheritance. If that's not possible you may be better off with a different pattern like mixins. This post has some good examples: [Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way).

Comment: "Can I perform multiple inheritance(python 3) using the super keyword if my child class inherits more than 1 class?" Yes, that is actually the entire point of super, to facilitate cooperative multiple inheritance. See this talk: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo