# Problems with multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a fundamental class called **MetaFunction**

```
class MetaFunction(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(
            self,
            pickle_data: PickleData,
            eth_protocols: Protocols = (),
            spi_protocols: Protocols = ()
    )
```

Class **AEB** inherits from **MetaFunction**:

```
class AEB(MetaFunction):

    def __init__(
            self,
            pickle_data: PickleData,
            eth_protocols: Protocols = (),
            spi_protocols: Protocols = (),
    ):
                    super().__init__(
                pickle_data=pickle_data,
                eth_protocols=eth_protocols,
                spi_protocols=spi_protocols
            )
```

But there is also a second base class except **MetaFunction** called **EventFinder**:

```
class EventFinder:
    def __init__(self, pickle_filename, export_path):
```

The final child class that I want to create is **AEBEventFinder**:

```
class AEBEventFinder(AEB, EventFinder):
    def __init__(
            self,
            pickle_filename: str,
            export_path: str,
            pickle_data: PickleData,
            eth_protocols: Protocols = (),
            spi_protocols: Protocols = ()
    ):
        AEB.__init__(
            self,
            pickle_data=pickle_data,
            eth_protocols=eth_protocols,
            spi_protocols=spi_protocols,
        )
        EventFinder.__init__(
            self,
            pickle_filename=pickle_filename,
            export_path=export_path
        )
```

As you can see it inherits from both AEB and EventFinder classes. I solved it using the old approach.
None of these worked for me: **[Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way)**

```
    super().__init__(
        pickle_data=pickle_data,
        eth_protocols=eth_protocols,
        spi_protocols=spi_protocols,
    )
    super(EventFinder, self).__init__(
        pickle_filename=pickle_filename,
        export_path=export_path
    )
```

According to the link above, I get the following error:
**TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)**

How can I solve it using the appropriate 'new' pythonic way?

**SOLVED**
Added **kwargs to each parent class (MetaFunction, AEB, EventFinder) and it worked. No implicit super().**init**() call in each parent class is needed! ;)

Comment: Can you give us the full error message, including stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your parent classes to accept all keyword arguments and just use the ones they recognize. And then you can use `super` as intended:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta
PickleData = Protocols = object

class MetaFunction(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(
        self,
        pickle_data: PickleData,
        eth_protocols: Protocols = (),
        spi_protocols: Protocols = (),
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            pickle_data=pickle_data,
            eth_protocols=eth_protocols,
            spi_protocols=spi_protocols,
            **kwargs,
        )

        
class AEB(MetaFunction):

    def __init__(
        self,
        pickle_data: PickleData,
        eth_protocols: Protocols = (),
        spi_protocols: Protocols = (),
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            pickle_data=pickle_data,
            eth_protocols=eth_protocols,
            spi_protocols=spi_protocols,
            **kwargs,
            )

        
class EventFinder:
    foo = 'foo'
    def __init__(self, pickle_filename, export_path, **kwargs):
        self.bar = 'bar'        

        
class AEBEventFinder(AEB, EventFinder):
    def __init__(self, my_own_argument, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # do something with my_own_argument
        
mytest = AEBEventFinder(pickle_data=None, pickle_filename='fn', export_path='.', my_own_argument='blah')
assert mytest.foo == 'foo'
assert mytest.bar == 'bar'
```

If the parent classes are beyond your control and are uncooperative by not accepting arguments they don't recognize, you can write an adapter that wraps them.

Raymond Hettinger has given a great primer ["Super considered super"](https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo) at PyCon.

Comment: It seems like it does not inherit any attributes from EventFinder class :/

Comment: @FilipSzczybura That must be a different problem. I've changed the example to show attributes work fine.

Comment: I solved it by removing super() call in each parent class. Addition of kwargs did the job