# ChildClass object has no attribute bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
class Foo(Baz, Qux):
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(bar=bar, *args, **kwargs)

class Baz:   
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bar = bar
```

This is the structure of my classes with the Foo class inheriting the Baz class. However when I try running the code, I get the following error
`Foo object has no attribute bar`

From what I understand, the `super(childclass, self).__init__(parent, attributes)` should initialize the parent class as well. Why should `bar` be present in the child class too?

I followed the following stack answers to implement this: [Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way)

**EDIT**

```
class Qux:   
    def __init__(self, xyz, *args, **kwargs):
        self.xyz = xyz
    
    def print_barqux(self):
        print(self.xyz)
        
class Baz:   
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bar = bar
        
class Foo(Baz, Qux):
    def __init__(self, bar, xyz, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(bar=bar, xyz=xyz)

    def printbar(self):
        super(Foo, self).print_barqux()
        
        
foo = Foo(bar="abcd", xyz="abcdef")
print(foo.printbar())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 17, in printbar
  File "./prog.py", line 6, in print_barqux
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'xyz'
```

Adding the error stacktrace with code

Comment: Shouldn't ```Baz``` be before ```Foo```?

Comment: Does the ordering matter? Anyways, in reality they are in different files. This was just a representation.

Comment: Have you tried the above code?   Please provide a minimal running example to demonstrate the error as well as the full traceback error.

Comment: _Does the ordering matter?_  Heck, yes.  `Baz` has to be fully defined before you can reference it as a base class for `Foo`.

Comment: If you have multiple inheritance like this, then `super` might not be the right answer.  You can specifically target `Baz` by doing `Baz.__init__(self, bar=bar, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @TimRoberts well, the whole *point* of `super` is to aid in cooperative multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ewong I have added a sample code with the traceback.

Comment: I always get the MRO confused, but unless `Qux` calls `super().__init__` as well, `Baz` might not be initialised…

Comment: But Qux doesn't have any parent classes right? I thought super was only for initialising parent classes. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Anyways, I tried adding
`super(Qux, self).__init__()`  as well as `super(Qux, self).__init__(xyz=xyz)` the error seems to persist

Comment: Super calls the next class in the MRO, which might be a parent class, or the other parent of a child class. In this case, calling `super()` in `Qux` calls `__init__` in `Baz`

Comment: I had a misconception wherein I thought both the parent classs where initialized through the child class itself. Slightly confusing. Makes sense. Thanks @mousetail

Comment: @SwastikUdupa no `super` *calls the next class in the method resolution order*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class has to call `super.__init__`:

```
class Qux:   
    def __init__(self, xyz, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.xyz = xyz
    
    def print_barqux(self):
        print(self.xyz)
        
class Baz:   
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar
        
class Foo(Baz, Qux):
    def __init__(self, bar, xyz, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(bar=bar, xyz=xyz)

    def printbar(self):
        super().print_barqux()
        
        
foo = Foo(bar="abcd", xyz="abcdef")
print(foo.printbar())
```