# Hybrid Inheritance

Tags: python

Stuck trying to figure out what is causing the error:
TypeError: **init**() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
Any help is appreciated.

```
# Parent class
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
# Child class
class Labrador(Dog):
    def __init__(self, name, age, playfulness):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.playfulness = playfulness
# Child class
class Poodle(Dog):
    def __init__(self, name, age, potty_trained):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.potty_trained = potty_trained
# Grandchild class
class Labradoodle(Labrador,Poodle):
    def __init__(self, name, age, playfulness, potty_trained):
        super().__init__(name, age, playfulness, potty_trained)

dogo2 = Labradoodle("Dookie", 2, 'Very playful', 'Yes')

print(dogo2.playfulness, dogo2.potty_trained)
```

Comment: When you do `super().__init__(name, age, playfulness, potty_trained)`, which function do you imagine is getting called? Normally you'd specify which superclass constructor you're calling - e.g. `super(Poodle).__init__(name, age, potty_trained)` and/or `super(Labrador).__init__(name, age, playfulness)`. But neither of those superclass constructors can handle all four arguments.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Ok, makes sense, but what if I want to get one parameter from the Poodle child class and one from the Labrador child class?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy no, that's absolutely not how it works. You would call `super(Labradoodle, self).__init__` pretty much always, or you could use the convenient zero-argument form which is equivalent to that

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy So, both `super(Labrador, self).__init__(name, age, playfulness)` and `super(Poodle, self).__init__(name, age, potty_trained)` *would end up calling `Dog.__init__`* which would error. If you want to call a *specific* `__init__`, then you just use `Labrador.__init__` or `Poodle.__init__`

Answer (score 2):

That is not how multiple inheritance works: you have to follow the **MRO** to know to which base class you're actually referring to.

In this case `super()` is calling `Labrador`'s constructor, simply because it's listed first in `Labradoodle`'s definition, so you have to fulfill its requirements (3 parameters)

Moreover, what you're implementing there is a sort of anti-pattern known as the **diamond** inheritance tree, which is a highly unadvisable practice, as it leads to many inheritance ambiguities. Generally prefer composition over multiple inheritance, at least whenever it's possible.

However, composition doesn't fit too well in this case; I think here the best solution is to derive `Labradoodle` from `Dog` too and add both `playfulness` and `potty_trained` as instance variables.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about the the diamond inheritance. Although there is a way out of it, it is not advisable. I was just trying to make sense of all these types of inheritance. I came across this website where they use the way I posted here, getting parameters from two Child classes, but I couldn't get it to work.
https://www.edureka.co/blog/inheritance-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are calling `super().__init__` in Labradoodle with more arguments than you should. The `__init__` that is being called is the `Labrador` one, which only contains 3 arguments.

You can read up more on what gets called in these cases here: [Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way)

Comment: Ok, I read it, that was helpful. So basically you can't call parameters from differnt child classes? You'd have to specify which child class you want in the super() function?

Comment: @RobinSage **no absolutely not** That defeats the entire purpose of super.