# Python multiple inheritance confusion

Tags: python, inheritance, derived-class

I've been trying to understand how to make sure all `super().__init__()`s run when writing a class that inherits from two *unrelated* classes. Based on answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way) and others like it, calling `super(DerivedClass, self).__init__()` should do the trick ("newer style").

So I've set up a dummy example:

```
class One():
    def __init__(self):
        print("One runs")
        self.one = 1
        
class Two():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Two runs")
        self.two = 2
        
        
class Three(One, Two):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Three, self).__init__()
        print("Three runs")

three = Three()
print(three.two)
```

To my biggest surprise, this results in an error when running on Python 3.9.7. The exact output I get is:

```
One runs
Three runs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/xd/f8xs148x2j18h636phmf27zh0000gq/T/ipykernel_7384/3344160392.py in <module>
     16 
     17 three = Three()
---> 18 print(three.two)

AttributeError: 'Three' object has no attribute 'two'
```

This makes me super confused. Is this not the right way to do it with the "newer style"? What am I missing?

Comment: The [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50465583/5349916) shows that you have to make *two* calls to ``super(...).__init__`` – one for each base. See the first case "1. The base classes are unrelated, standalone classes." Other answers are showing a similar pattern for this case.

Comment: Take note that this question linked to another *question*, not an answer. Either way, as mentioned there are many answers on that question that show *that* and *why* two super calls are required, i.e. that "calling ``super(DerivedClass, self).__init__()`` should do the trick" is not the case and what to do instead. If you can [edit] this question to clarify in how far the information in the other one is not sufficient, it will go to the reopen process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `__init__` is *not* run, because you didn't use `super` properly. When designing a class hierarchy that uses `super`, it's important that *all* the classes use it.

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("One runs")
        self.one = 1
        
class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Two runs")
        self.two = 2
        
        
class Three(One, Two):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Three runs")
```

While the inheritance graph is a directed acyclic graph, the method resolution order is a linear ordering of the nodes in that tree. `super` uses that list, not the graph itself, when determining which method gets called via `super()`.

```
>>> Three.mro()
[<class '__main__.Three'>, <class '__main__.One'>, <class '__main__.Two'>, <class 'object'>]
```

`Three()` calls `Three.__init__`, which calls `One.__init__`, which calls `Two.__init__`, which calls `object.__init__`, which calls nothing because `object.__init__` is the top of the chain for `__init__`.

More detail can be found in [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), which also provides advice on how to adapt `One` and `Two` when they don't already use `super`.

Comment: Why would `One.__init__` call `Two.__init__`?  `One` doesn't know about `Two`.

Comment: It doesn't need to; `super()` use the method resolution order of the object bound to `self`, which *does* know about all the classes involved. `super` is misnamed, and does not just refer to the static parent (or one of the static parents) of the class being defined.

Comment: @chepner yep, exactly. `next` might have been a better name (obviously alreaady taken), or maybe `next_class`, because what it does it get you *the next class in the method resolution order*.

Comment: Dylan (which I think is where `super` drew inspiration from) called it `next-method` :)