# Inheriting more than 1 parent class in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to inherit 2 classes as parent class in a child class both have different class variables **class A** has a,b while **class B** has c,d,e they are the parent to **class AB(A,B)** now i want to make an object of AB class but i am not able understand how to pass the value while i try to create an object of AB class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def testa(self):
        print('inside A')
class B:
    def __init__(self,c,d,e):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
    def testb(self):
        print('inside B')

class AB(A,B):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        A.__init__(self,*args)
        B.__init__(self,*args)
```

obj = AB(1,2,3) # this is throwing error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling parent class \_\_init\_\_ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way)

Answer (score 0):

`*args` will always unpack all values. And as `A` only expects 2 values it throws an error, when you pass 3 values. To limit `args` to 2 elements use `slicing [:2]` if you want to pass the first 2 elements to `A`

So your `AB`'s `init` should look like this:

```py
class AB(A,B):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        A.__init__(self, *args[:2])
        B.__init__(self, *args)
```

Additionally, you'll run into an error with your methods `testa` and `testb` as they are missing `self` which is always passed to methods of an instance.

Just add `self` to both methods to avoid a `TypeError`

```py
def testa(self):
        print('inside A')
```