# How to construct a Python object with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I succeeded to construct a Python object with multiple inheritance but I feel like I didn't use the proper way...

Here is my code :

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print("A ctor called!")
        self.a_ = a

    def printa(self):
        print(self.a_)


class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        print("B ctor called!")
        self.b_ = b
    
    def printb(self):
        print(self.b_)


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a_ = a
        self.b_ = b
        self.c_ = c
```

If I type :

```py
c = C(11, 22, 33)
c.printb()
```

The output is :

```py
22
```

which is what I wanted. But the thing which puzzles me is that I managed to build an object from my class `C` without calling constructors from class `A` and `B`...

Is it normal or did I do something wrong ?

I think what I should do is using the `super()` function but I don't know how to use it with multiple inheritance to call both parents `A` and `B`...

Cheers

EDIT : My question has been labelled as a duplicate but I'm not sure it is totally one. In this topic [Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way) this issue doesn't deal with constructors with parameters. But in my question, it's the parameters that entail the problem.

Comment: Your `C.__init__` is actually doing all the initialization that is supposed to be done by parent(s) `__init__`. i.e. it duplicates the code in parents.

Comment: That's the only fix I've managed to find. It's also possible to use this syntax which might be better : A.__init__(self, a) and B.__init__(self, b) In this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way it's mentioned as the old-style way to handle this problem. It's the only way that worked for me but the fact it doesn't use `super()` is puzzling. Moreover, it's a technic I didn't find anywhere else.

Comment: `super` will be difficult here, since both parent `__init__` use different arguments. You will have to call each parent `__init__` separately and pass them the argument they expect. There really isn't a lot of magic here. You're literally just calling a function with sets an attribute on the passed object (`self`). That's it. No more, no less. `super()` just resolves the parent class in a specific way, but will ultimately not do anything differently.

Comment: @deceze thx! and do you know if A.__init__(self, a) and B.__init__(self, b) is the only and proper way to implement this solution or not ?