TypeError: Technician.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'specialization'
I'm trying to do my homework on object-oriented programming but I get a weird error
tried restarting vscode or changing names
Objective: To develop an employee management system that demonstrates multiple inheritance, encapsulation, and polymorphism in Python. The system should manage various types of activities, including managers and technical specialists, and provide opportunities for expansion and addition of new roles.
class Employee: #parent class
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, id, department):
        super().__init__(name, id)
        self.department = department

class Technician(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, id, specialization):
        super().__init__(name, id)
        self.specialization = specialization

class TechManager(Manager, Technician):
    def __init__(self, name, id, department, specialization):
        Manager.__init__(self, name, id, department)
        Technician.__init__(self, name, id, specialization)
        self.subordinates = []

    def add_employee(self, employee):
        self.subordinates.append(employee)

    def get_team_info(self):
        subordinates_info = [employee.get_info() for employee in self.team]
        print(f"Список подчиненных:\n" + "\n".join(subordinates_info))

employee1 = Employee("Сергей", 1)
manager1 = Manager("Денис", 2, "ит")
technician1 = Technician("Петр", 3, "ии")
techManager1 = TechManager("Андрей", 4, "ит", "ии")

I get this error message
PS C:\Users\EvoTechPC> & C:/Users/EvoTechPC/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/EvoTechPC/Desktop/учеба/ввит/lab7/Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\EvoTechPC\Desktop\учеба\ввит\lab7\Main.py", line 41, in <module>
    techManager1 = TechManager("Андрей", 4, "ит", "ии")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\EvoTechPC\Desktop\учеба\ввит\lab7\Main.py", line 27, in __init__
    Manager.__init__(self, name, id, department)  # Инициализация Manager с нужными аргументами
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\EvoTechPC\Desktop\учеба\ввит\lab7\Main.py", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, id)
TypeError: Technician.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'specialization'

Task is:

Create an Employee class with common attributes like name (name), id (identification number), and methods like get_info() that returns basic information about the employee.

Create a Manager class with traditional attributes like department (department) and methods like Manage_project() that symbolize managing projects.

Create a Technician class with respect to attributes like specialization (specialization) and methods like Perform_maintenance() that mean performing maintenance.

Create a TechManager class that becomes a manager as well as a technician. This class should combine management skills and technical skills, for example having methods for managing projects and performing maintenance.

Add an add_employee() method that allows the TechManager administrator to list subordinates.

Implement the get_team_info() method that displays information about all subordinate employees.


If anyone can help me I would be very grateful

You're doing three things here that just don't work together - multiple inheritance, use of super(), and classes with different initialization parameters.  Any two of those work just fine, but not all three.  Specifically, in the presence of multiple inheritance, those calls to super().__init__() are not necessarily calling the parent class (instead, they call the next class in method resolution order), so there's no easy way to tell what parameters you'd need to pass.  Simplest solution would be to explicitly name the parent class everywhere, as you're currently doing in TechManager.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way but it's not an obvious duplicate. Reading the answer there, I don't see how to fix your code yet, but it should be a helpful place to start.

Oh, wait, I figured it out: it's in Manager you need a fix: instead of using super(), there, if you use Employee.__init__(self, name, id) then your code works. You probably want to use this style of calling parent initialization everywhere.
